# Passing row data from DataTables to method in controller with parameter row data

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a link in my datatable that will call a method in my controller and pass the row data as my parameter. but the value showing is [Object] [object] how should i pass it on my controller method as a list or dictionary?

I already tried to stringtify but it has an error showing that the query string is too long.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: urlGetRequest,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (resultdata) {
            data = resultdata.aaData;
            if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblSolutioning')) {
                $('#tblSolutioning').DataTable().destroy();
            }
            $("#tblSolutioning").DataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aaData": data,
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "mData": "RequestID",
                        "bSearchable": true,
                        "bSortable": true,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row, meta) {

                            //return '<a href="#"  onclick="ManageSolutionModal(\'' + row + '\')">' + data + '</a>'; 

                            return "<a href='ManageSolution?rowRequest= " + rowData + " '  onclick='setBackUrl(window.location.href)'>" + data + "</a>"; 

                        }

                    },

                ],

                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": '_all',
                    "searchable": true
                }]
            });


        }
    });


        public ActionResult ManageSolution(Dictionary<string,string> rowRequest)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What `value` is returning `[Object] [object]`? Where is `rowData` defined?

Comment: the value of row is actually depend on the selected row you clicked.   I wanted to pass that row data as parameter on my controller but it was not available on query string because it is object. wehn i tried to stringtify to convert it to string it has an error that the string is too long. My question is how i can send that row data to my controller and eventually run its view. i already tried also calling another function to pass the data but the view is not changing.

Comment: Why not click on the row and pass `row` as parameter to a function and that function makes an ajax request to your controller parsing that parameter? Try to make a JSFiddle with dummy data so it's easier to help you.